# Log on to SharePoint with Powershell using the Credential Manager

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

What I would like is to logon to sharepoint with powershell using the CSOM-module and using the Credential Manager where I have safely stored the password.

This is a working code to logon to sharepoint

```
    Try 
    {
          $Credentials = New-Object 
          Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user,(ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force))
           $Context =  New-Object 
           Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
            $Context.Credentials = $Credentials
     }
     Catch 
     {
        exit 
     }
```

But how can I use the credential manager. I have installed the module en made this:

```
#$managedCred = Get-StoredCredential -Target SharepointOnline
```

Does anyone know the solution.

Gr P

Answer (score 1):

Peter, I have answered the same question posted by you in another Technet Thread, please remember to check it:

[[TechNet] Log on to SharePoint with Powershell using the Credential Manager](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9c9cca7c-5758-4132-aed9-49af602faec7/log-on-to-sharepoint-with-powershell-using-the-credential-manager?forum=SP2019)

Hi PeetK,

Firstly, create a Generic Credentials in Credential Manager:

[image]

In my side, the name is "o365" for example, then in PowerShell, use like this:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$cred = Get-StoredCredential -Target 'o365'  
#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://TenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($cred.UserName,$cred.Password)

#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$Web=$Context.Web;
$Context.Load($Web)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/103660)

Comment: @Gaurravs, OK, I will update my reply above to include detailed content.

Comment: @Gaurravs,Done, please check.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with PnP PowerShell. I use this all the time as I have dozens of client environments I connect to.

```
Connect-PnPOnline <url> -Credential <name of stored credential>
```

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/wiki/How-to-use-the-Windows-Credential-Manager-to-ease-authentication-with-PnP-PowerShell#label-approach

If you want to do this without PnP you can check out the code on Github and reverse engineer it.